# Powershell, checking new table for $null values

Tags: powershell

I created a script to help us inventory our machines.  Its been sucessuful and in the end I create a Table and that object is exported to a CSV.

A large handful of machines return no values from time to time (RPC Service Unavailable).  How would I go about checking to see if every value was returned?  If no values are turned, I want to add those machines to a separate list for troubleshooting.  What would be the most efficient way of checking?

```
$table = @{
Model= $PCInfo.Model
IEVersion = $ie.sValue 
Serial = $Bios.SerialNumber
Memory = $ram
Department = $dp.Department
DriveFreeSpaceGB = $freespace
Manufacturer = $PCInfo.Manufacturer
OSName = $WinInfo.Caption
Computer = $computer
Uptime = $formattime
LastloggedinUser = $Uname.name
LastLoggedinDate = $loggedintime
LoggedOnDuringScan = $PCInfo.Username
ServicePack = $WinInfo.ServicePackMajorVersion
Online = $Online
    } 
New-Object PSObject -Property $table | Export-Csv C:\logs\ADInventory\ADInventory.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
`If no values are turned`. This could mean that the $table object is null and you can check if `$table` is null or not.

```
if($table -eq $null){
#do something here
Write-host "your object is null"
}
else{
#export the objects to csv file
}
```

2) `RPC Service Unavailable`. If you know that service is the problem then you can check if the service is running or not using wmi.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the new object to a variable then check for null properties:

```
$pso = New-Object PSObject -Property $table
$pso.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object {$_.value -eq $null}
```

Comment: how would you do when you don't know which property can be null?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using WMI etc to fill those '$PCinfo' type variables. As I have gone through the same kind of exercise myself, I would suggest you turn them into functions and build logic into return function of the script like:

```
Function Get-PcInfo {

  if ($SystemInfo = Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem) {
    return $SystemInfo.Model 
  }

  return $false  ##or use $null if you like
}
```

So now you will have some (or all) hash 'values' as $false and you can use Hash properties (like .values) to check for $false.

Similarly, f you use $null, you would need to check the result. One way could be to use some logic like this:

```
if ($hash.Values | ? {$_ -ne $null}) {"not null"}
```